# How to align the ANN_DT (financial data announcement date) in df1 with the TRADE_DT (trading date) in df2 using the join_asof function in Polars?

Tags: date, group-by, python-polars

tradedates_code = AShareEodPrices[['S_INFO_WINDCODE','TRADE_DT']]
trade_dates = tradedates_code.filter(pl.col('TRADE_DT') >= 20100101).select('TRADE_DT').set_sorted('TRADE_DT')

AShareFinancialIndicator = AShareFinancialIndicator.sort(['S_INFO_WINDCODE', 'ANN_DT']).set_sorted('ANN_DT'))

AShareFinancialIndicator = AShareFinancialIndicator.join_asof(
trade_dates,
left_on='ANN_DT',
right_on='TRADE_DT',
strategy='forward'  # The most recent TRADE_DT that is greater than ANN_DT
)

AShareFinancialIndicator.select(['S_INFO_WINDCODE','ANN_DT','TRADE_DT']).tail(100)

```
S_INFO_WINDCODE ANN_DT  TRADE_DT
str i64 i64
"873919.BJ" 20231222    null
"873931.BJ" 20201211    null
"873931.BJ" 20211103    null
"873931.BJ" 20230218    null
"873931.BJ" 20230427    null
"873931.BJ" 20230831    null
"873931.BJ" 20231121    null
"873989.BJ" 20221101    null
"873989.BJ" 20230426    null
"873989.BJ" 20230830    null
"873989.BJ" 20231220    null
"874007.BJ" 20111124    null
…   …   …
"874232.BJ" 20231114    null
"874232.BJ" 20231207    null
"874232.BJ" 20231220    null
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMy19.png)

I suspect that the sorting of ANN_DT across different stocks might get mixed up, which doesn't comply with the sorted requirement for asof_join? However, I'm not quite sure how to perform asof_join after grouping by stock. My requirement is to add a TRADE_DT column (the actual stock trading date) to a table containing the ANN_DT field (the actual financial announcement date), with the condition that TRADE_DT ≥ ANN_DT.

Comment: I solved it by only sorting by date, without letting the stock code participate in the sorting.

AShareFinancialIndicator = AShareFinancialIndicator.sort('ANN_DT').set_sorted('ANN_DT')

AShareTTMHis = AShareTTMHis.sort('ANN_DT').set_sorted('ANN_DT')